# Align jQuery Tipsy To Left Edge Of Element

Tags: jquery, tipsy

I'm using the [jQuery Tipsy Plugin](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) to create tool tips in my project. Tooltips are automatically centred to the element, as seen on the plugin pages demos, but I'd like it to align to the left of element, does anyone know a method to do this? The plugin automatically sets an absolute position of the tooltip when displayed, I've tried altering this function but have had no luck.

**Update 1**: I am well aware of the docs and the `gravity` option, I am looking to centre the tooltips arrow to the **left edge** of it's corresponding element.

**Update 2**: Here's a mock up of how I want the tooltip to be placed:
[image: Left: Current, Right: Intended]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, I was editing the wrong function. It turn's out there was another function specially for 'NW/SW' gravities, updated JS:

```
            if (gravity.length == 2) {
                if (gravity.charAt(1) == 'w') {
                    tp.left = pos.left - 5;
                } else {
                    tp.left = pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth + 15;
                }
            }
```

I'm going to fork this on Git incase other's need this functionality.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting back your solution for others that may have the same question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my apologies for my poor communication initially.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the position based on the gravity option:

```
$('#foo').tipsy({gravity: 'e'});  // these are coordinates: // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se
```

The information on the options for the plugin can be found on this page.   See the section called gravities for more information or other configuration options.

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/#

Comment: Sorry someone posted this exact answer, I commented explaining why it was wrong, and they must of deleted it. Apologies, thank you for answering, I am well aware of the docs, but I went to align the tooltip's tip to the **left edge** of the element, and not to the centre.

Comment: @RyanBrodie I'm confused, can you post a screenshot of what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ryan for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. I went a bit further with your code and gave more functionality.

I added 2 new options to tipsy so that it does the following:

- On `sw`/`nw`, you can use `edgeAlignWest: 'right'` or `edgeAlignWest: 'center'`
- On `se`/`ne`, you can use `edgeAlignEast: 'left'` or `edgeAlignEast: 'center'`

The new code to do this is

```
// line 61, tipsy version 1.0.0a
if (gravity.length == 2) {
    if (gravity.charAt(1) == 'e') {
        tp.left = (this.options.edgeAlignEast == 'right') ? (pos.left + pos.width - actualWidth + 15) : (pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth + 15);
    }else if (gravity.charAt(1) == 'w') {
        tp.left = (this.options.edgeAlignWest == 'left') ? (pos.left - 5) : (pos.left + pos.width / 2 - 15);
    } else {
      tp.left = pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth + 15;
  }
}

//...
// line 191, tipsy version 1.0.0a
$.fn.tipsy.defaults = {
    edgeAlignEast: 'center',  // <-- new option, default to 'center', you can also use 'right'
    edgeAlignWest: 'center',  // <-- new option, default to 'center', you can also use 'left'
    className: null,
    delayIn: 0,
    delayOut: 0,
    fade: false,
    fallback: '',
    gravity: 'n',
    html: false,
    live: false,
    offset: 0,
    opacity: 0.8,
    title: 'title',
    trigger: 'hover'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source (at line 43),

I find this,

```
case 'n':
tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height + this.options.offset, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2};
```

I guess changing the `left` should do the trick.

Comment: I think that's what the OP is asking as to what that should be set to.

Comment: `The plugin automatically sets an absolute position of the tooltip when displayed, I've tried altering this function but have had no luck.` Yes I was looking for that function to be altered?

Comment: 'How something can set something automatically if you have source code' ? By the way, have you tried setting `left: 0` ?